# linux cpu usage

Tags: linux

I am working on unix.
I want to knwo the current cpu usage of a process.
I understood that ps give the average of cpu used till the process is up - it is not the current usage.

Is there a way to print only the cpu from the top command without 10 more parameters and 
headers? I know how to do it with awk - this is not the way i want to do it.

```
top  -p 20705 -bc -n 1  | tail -n 2 | awk '{ print $9}' | head -n 1
```

If there is another simple way to do it, not reading /proc/stat...

If there is a simple way doing it from c++, it is also ok.

Comment: Why don't you want to read `/proc/stat...` ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard command which can do this directly.

Comment: AFAIK, the percentage shown in top is the percentage of time that the scheduler scheduled that process to be run. It is not the percentage of the cpu being used. Maybe that's splitting hairs, but I thought it was worth mentioning. Although they are most likely very similar, I can think of cases where they might be different.

Comment: It returns `signal 11 (SEGV) was caught by top, please send bug reports to <procps@freelists.org>`

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you will need to read `/proc/stat`, However, [here is an interesting article with C code](http://brokestream.com/procstat.html) that may help you out. To understand and use the output from the program you should do `man 5 proc`. And here is the [source code](http://brokestream.com/procstat.c).

The bottom line is that you will need to read from `/proc/stat` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

to see cpu usage of a proccess whose pid is 24556

```
ps -p 24556 -o \%cpu=
```

to see mem usage of a process named syslogd

```
ps -C syslogd -o \%mem=
```

Comment: I understood that ps give the average of cpu used till the process is up - it is not the current usage.

Comment: This returns nothing